# Finding minimum index of a sub-list of a list

Tags: python

Say, I have a list and a sub-list constructed from that list. I want to find the number from the sub-list that appears earliest in the original list.

Example:

```
lst = [5, 3, 4, 1, 2, 6]
sublst = [1, 2, 3]
```

In this case, I want to select 3 since it appears in `lst` 2nd, while 1 and 2 appear 4th and 5th respectively. What I have so far:

```
lst[min(lst.index(num) for num in sublst)]
```

This seems really convoluted and difficult-to-read. I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to write this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make `sublst` a set to make it more efficient to search in it. Then you could use a simple `for` loop:

```
lst = [5, 3, 4, 1, 2, 6]
sublst = set([1, 2, 3])
for l in lst:
    if l in sublst:
        break
print(l)
```

You could also write that as a generator comprehension, finding all values in `lst` that are in `sublst`. By using a generator we will stop at the first matching value:

```
first = (l for l in lst if l in sublst)
print(next(first))
```

Output in both cases for your sample data is

```
3
```

Comment: Two efficiency improvements here: (1) make `sublst` a set, and (2) replace the list comprehension with a generator, so you don’t compute any indices beyond the first.